# Einstein Content Selection / Attribute mapping

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I want to discover the potential of the Einstein Content Selection feature.
And therefore I have some ambiguities.

- It is said I have to "Pick a sendable data extension with customer profile data that Einstein Content Selection can use." Does that has to be the Send-DE for further sends when I want to use the einstein content block?
- Do I have to use the same value in asset attribut compared to a value of the consumer attribute? (e.g. field "hobby" value "swimmimng" --> consumer attribute maps on "sports" value "swimming". correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point you are asking about is quite simple to answer:

The DataExtension you will use for sending (has to be a sendable DataExtension) is a template for the dataextensions you will usually use. When you select a dataextension with fields like "sports","language","country", then the other dataextensions you are normally sending with should also have these columns. This way Einstein Content Selection knows which column it has to search for. You do not need to send every send to the dataextension that you selected here.

To the second point:

When your content has field "hobby" and value "swimming" you would try to match it to a customer column that is available in your sending data extensions / or in your subscriber attributes (if you use them). Therefore your assumption you did is correct. Just make sure that the values actually have the same kind of "set" or are atleast a subset.